# Get frame contents with jQuery

Tags: jquery

**main.html** has this code:

```
<iframe id="myframe" src="myframe.html"></iframe>
```

and I trigger this code inside main.html:

```
alert($('#myframe').contents().find('#mypage').contents().find('html').html());
```

**myframe.html** has this code:

```
<frameset>
<frame id="mypage" src="mypage.html">
</frameset>
```

**mypage.html** has all this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
hello world!
</html>
```

I want to get all the HTML code of the mypage.html from within the main.html page, but I fail. What is the problem with the way I do it?

Comment: Please consider extracting your exact problem and asking it. "Can't make it work" is not a question.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem.

I was able to resolve it.

In my example:

```
myframe = ReportFrameReportViewerControl
mypage = report
```

This is the code to get the html (note that all sites need to be on the same domain):

```
function bla()
{
    var str = 
    $(
            $(
                $("#ReportFrameReportViewerControl")[0].contentWindow.document
            )
            .find("#report")[0].contentWindow.document
        ).find("html").html()
        ;

        alert(str);
}
```

You might want to place it onto a button that you can press once the page loaded:

```
<input type="button" value="test" onclick="bla();" />
```

Also, if you want to get the html automagically once the page is loaded, you need to register the onload function of both myframe & mypage.

Like this (replace setTableSize with bla):

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    $('#ReportFrameReportViewerControl').load(function () 
    {
        //setNewHeight();
        //alert("Loading");

        setTableSize();

        $(
            $("#ReportFrameReportViewerControl")[0].contentWindow.document
        )
        .find("#report").load(function () 
        {
            //alert("load report");
            setTableSize();
        }
        ); // End load #report


    }); // End Function load #ReportFrameReportViewerControl


}); // End Function document.ready
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically I don't think you can do it with the frames as that would be a security problem.

You could load the source of the inner frame with ajax if you really needed to get at it. But it certainly wouldn't be live

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to include the jquery library at main.html.
Secondly,
Chrome returns the next error:

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access
>   frame with URL file:///../myframe.html
>   from frame with URL
>   file:///../main.html. Domains,
>   protocols and ports must match.

So it's a security problem